# Export emails with remote content included

Tags: email, export

How do I export emails from Microsoft Outlook software (or Thunderbird or EPIM or EMclient) so that I can view exported emails offline with pictures and attachments included too? Remote content needs to be included for offline viewing too.

I don’t want to click manually on every email (and wait 1 second per email) for it to load remote content and then export to MSG or PDF, I have way to many emails. I need this automatically.

Do not write about setting it up in TRUST CENTER etc., I already did it.

Comment: Who's your email provider? What OS are you using?

Comment: Gmail. I have Outlook 2007 and 2016 email client on Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

I've personally never tried it, but you could try following [this Google help article](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en) which describes how you can download your Google account data - including Gmail data. Whether this includes remote content, I don't know, but it outputs the mail data as an MBOX format. To read this, you can use Mozilla Thunderbird. There are some guides on how to do this online, including [this one from MakeUseOf](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-downloaded-gmail-data/) and [this one from some university](https://it.stonybrook.edu/help/kb/reading-mbox-files-from-google-takeout-take-your-email-messages-with-you). Hopefully this gives you a start.